# Move file recursively to parent folder

Tags: batch, powershell, vlc-media-player

I'm on windows 10, I need a batch script or a powershell script to solve this problem.

I have downloaded the flash tv series, the structure looks like this

```
    flash tv series folder
episode 1 folder
episode 2 folder
episode 3 folder
...
```

And the movie files are inside the episodes folders along with subtitles srt sometimes. The folders containing the episodes have different names. The episodes are sometimes mkv and mp4 mostly.

I want a script to search every folder inside `flash tv series` folder looking for mkv, mp4, srt and move them up to the parent folder so I can add them to a vlc or SMplayer playlist. Because now I can't do that.

Comment: We are not a scripting service.  So provide what you have attempted.  If you have not even attempted to write your own script this question is likely to be closed very quickly.

Comment: @Ramhound im not a windows user, I am stuck with it for now, I don't know batch nor powershell, so I haven't attempted anything, if I don't get an answer by tomorrow then I guess I'll be on my own, I'll move everything to linux and do it using python, perl or bash. windows is not my comfort zone.

Comment: @Lynob Python and Perl are available for Windows (and Python works pretty well on Windows, in my experience). If those are your preferred languages, this sounds like a great excuse to get them installed.

Comment: Also, isn't this a dup of http://superuser.com/q/999922/46507 ?

Comment: Well we are not a scritpt writing service.  So like I said unless you attempt it yourself this question will be closed. Help center goes into more detail why question like this are not considered helpful

Comment: If there's a specific, generally-applicable part you're stuck on, we can help you with that. You can also pop into chat; sometimes live help happens there.

Comment: @Ouroborus yes its a dupe and should be closed

Comment: @Ramhound yes it should be closed, i haven't noticed the dupe

Comment: @BenN true, shouldve asked on the chat first

Answer (score 3):

Hope this helps you. 
Run this within the "flash tv series folder" root folder

Just MK4's

```
forfiles /s /m *.mk4 /c "cmd /c move @path %CD%"
```

Everything Except for Directories...

```
forfiles /s /m * /c "cmd /c if @isdir==FALSE move @path %CD%"
```

Comment: I run it in cmd, I get `The syntax of this command is incorrect`