# Move all files from multiple subfolders into the one folder

Tags: windows, batch, cmd.exe

[Basically this](https://superuser.com/questions/999922/move-all-files-from-multiple-subfolders-into-the-parent-folder) I used `FOR /R "C:\Source Folder" %i IN (*.png) DO MOVE "%i" "C:\Staging Folder"` It worked flawlessly except that all of the .png files that I have are named exactly the same so when I execute it, it will keep asking if I want to overwrite it, how do I make it so the output name are in increment suffix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add a counter. I started with `10000` and took the last four digits only (resulting in files like `originalname-0001.png` etc. Simply expand it if a max of 9999 seems a bit tight)

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set counter=10000
FOR /R "C:\Source Folder" %%i IN (*.png) DO (
  set /a counter+=1
  MOVE "%%i" "C:\Staging Folder\%%~ni-!counter:~-4!%%~xi"
)
```

Comment: Thank you!.....