# How can I merge multiple folders and files to a new single folder?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, robocopy

I have a folder named `SCENERY` on drive `F` (`F:\SCENERY`). It contains several folders: `A`, `B`, `C`... etc. I would like to **merge** the contents of `A`, `B`, `C`... etc to another folder on drive `F` named `BASEFILES` (`F:\BASEFILES`).

Is this possible?

PowerShell script used & output:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> (Get-ChildItem 'F:\Scenery\*' -Directory).FullName |
ForEach-Object { Join-Path $_ '*' } |
Copy-Item -Destination 'F:\BaseFiles' -WhatIf
What if: Performing the operation "Copy Directory" on target "Item: F:\Scenery\XP11_HD_Mesh_V4\XP11_HD_Mesh_V4_+60-020-Europe Destination: F:\BaseFiles\XP11_HD_Mesh_V4_+60-020-Europe".
What if: Performing the operation "Copy Directory" on target "Item: F:\Scenery\XP11_HD_Mesh_V4\XP11_HD_Mesh_V4_+70+020-Europe Destination: F:\BaseFiles\XP11_HD_Mesh_V4_+70+020-Europe".
PS C:\Windows\system32>
```

Comment: Look at the `/LEV:n` argument. it does what you describe

Comment: Thank You Frank! :)  OK then i will try this with Easy ROBOCOPY. or maybe CMD!?

Comment: Sorry to say it did not work! it still copies  all folders below the source. Despite the /LEV:n switch.

Comment: when you use terms like below and above, there is a bit of ambiguity. do you imagine directory trees as Pines with the root at the top, or Shrubberies, with the roots at the bottom? /LEV controls how many levels it will recurse into. its not clear whether you mean to copy three levels deep from the root, or recurse in three levels before starting to copy.

Comment: No worries. ok that is the opposite of what LEV does. I'd probably write a powershell script to call robocopy in a loop, cd'ing into the level2 directory with each itteration, and copying their files/subdirs.

Comment: I am sorry for my bad explanation. I edited the original post above. Hope it is a little clearer! :)

Comment: OK, That explanes why it is hard to get any search results on google! lol.  Well i will have to look into this exciting part of computing! :)  Anyway, thank you so much Frank!.

Comment: [windows - Move all files from multiple subfolders into the parent folder - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/999922/move-all-files-from-multiple-subfolders-into-the-parent-folder/999966)

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the subfolders of `F:\SCENERY`, this **PowerShell** would work:

- The destination folder, `F:\BaseFiles`, should be created prior to
  running this command.

```
(Get-ChildItem 'F:\Scenery\*' -Directory).FullName |
     ForEach-Object { Join-Path $_ '*' } |
         Copy-Item -Destination 'F:\BaseFiles' -Recurse
```

### Edit:

Don't copy line-by-line, it's a single pipeline:

```
(Get-ChildItem 'F:\Scenery\*' -Directory).FullName | ForEach-Object { Join-Path $_ '*' } | Copy-Item -Destination 'F:\BaseFiles' -Recurse
```

- To verify what will happen, run this version first:

```
(Get-ChildItem 'F:\Scenery\*' -Directory).FullName |
     ForEach-Object { Join-Path $_ '*' } |
         Copy-Item -Destination 'F:\BaseFiles' -Recurse -WhatIf
```

- The `-WhatIf` parameter previews the operation without performing it.

Using aliases, the first command reduces to:

```
(gci 'F:\Scenery\*' -ad).FullName |
     % { Join-Path $_ '*' } |
         Copy -s 'F:\BaseFiles'
```

Comment: Thank You Keith! :) 
I Got the folders! :) , But nothing they contained. Neither files or folders.
Is it possible to modify the script? 
I tried my self, but i just mess things up.

Comment: Did you copy the entire code block and paste it at once -- not line by line?

Comment: If that wasn't the issue, edit your question and add a code block with a copy & paste the c ommand & its output from the **PowerShell** console.

Comment: I copied it as a single line, Not line by line!

Comment: I believe the `Copy-Item` command needs a `-Recurse`.

Comment: Yep! That did It! You guys are just great!!
Thank You Both helping me on this! :) 
/DaveM

Comment: Sorry, will edit. DIdn't have a clear idea of the folder structure..